# unable to construct runtime boost spsc_queue with runtime size parameter in shared memory

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

I want to make a lock free ring buffer in shared memory using runtime specified maximum number of entries.  I am basing my code off an example I found in [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/sehe/9376856).  I successfully created a lock free ring buffer in shared memory using this code.
In my case, I need to specify the maximum number of entries that the ring buffer can accept at runtime construction and not at compile time per the example. The call to construct the `shm::ring_buffer` in the example is shown below.

```
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;

namespace shm
{
    using char_alloc = bip::allocator<char, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
    using shared_string = bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, char_alloc>;
    using ring_buffer = boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<shared_string, boost::lockfree::capacity<200>>;
}
```

The shared memory segment is allocated as follows:

```
mQueuingSharedMem = std::make_unique<bip::managed_shared_memory>(
    bip::open_or_create, (mSharedMemoryName + "Queuing").c_str(), rSHMSize);
```

Per the GitHub example, when I construct the ring buffer with the maximum size specified at compile time via the optional `boost::lockfree::capacity<>` template parameter, everything works (note: that the shared memory segment `construct` method takes the # ring_buffers in the [] and the constructor parameters are specified in the parenthesis that follow.

```
auto pSharedMemAddr = mQueuingSharedMem->construct<
   shm::ring_buffer>(rQueuingPortName.c_str())[1](/*aMaxNumMessages*/);
```

I thought that in order to construct the above shm::ring_buffer at runtime, I needed to remove the 2nd `boost::lockfree::capacity<200>` hard coded size parameter from the `shm::spsc_queue` and instead pass a maximum size for the `shm::ring_buffer` and the shared memory allocator for the `shm::shm_string`.   I found a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729365/using-boostlockfreespsc-queue-with-an-allocator) but I was unable to adapt it to work with my code.

I made the following changes to the code that worked above in an attempt to specify the size of the ring buffer at runtime:

```
namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace shm
{
    using char_alloc = bip::allocator<char, bip::managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>;
    using shared_string = bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, char_alloc>;
    using ring_buffer = boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<shared_string/*, boost::lockfree::capacity<200>*/>;
}

    shm::char_alloc char_alloc(mQueuingSharedMem->get_segment_manager());
    auto pSharedMemAddr = mQueuingSharedMem->construct<
        shm::ring_buffer>(rQueuingPortName.c_str())[1](aMaxNumMessages);
```

I get a plethora of unintelligible compiler errors that I do not quite know how to fix:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: apex, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>APEXManager.cpp
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/container/string.hpp(216): error C2512: 'boost::interprocess::allocator<char,boost::interprocess::segment_manager<CharType,MemoryAlgorithm,IndexType>>::allocator': no appropriate default constructor available
1>        with
1>        [
1>            CharType=char,
1>            MemoryAlgorithm=boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family,boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void,ptrdiff_t,uintptr_t,0>,0>,
1>            IndexType=boost::interprocess::iset_index
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/container/string.hpp(214): note: while compiling class template member function 'boost::container::container_detail::basic_string_base<Allocator>::members_holder::members_holder(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Allocator=shm::char_alloc
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/container/string.hpp(100): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::container::container_detail::basic_string_base<Allocator>::members_holder::members_holder(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Allocator=shm::char_alloc
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/container/string.hpp(224): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::container::container_detail::basic_string_base<Allocator>::members_holder' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Allocator=shm::char_alloc
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/container/string.hpp(506): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::container::container_detail::basic_string_base<Allocator>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            Allocator=shm::char_alloc
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp(557): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::container::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,shm::char_alloc>' being compiled
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp(555): note: while compiling class template member function 'boost::lockfree::detail::runtime_sized_ringbuffer<T,std::allocator<T>>::~runtime_sized_ringbuffer(void)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=shm::shared_string
1>        ]
1>..\..\src\apex\APEXManager.cpp(660): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::lockfree::detail::runtime_sized_ringbuffer<T,std::allocator<T>>::~runtime_sized_ringbuffer(void)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=shm::shared_string
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp(693): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::lockfree::detail::runtime_sized_ringbuffer<T,std::allocator<T>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=shm::shared_string
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/interprocess/detail/in_place_interface.hpp(61): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<shm::shared_string>' being compiled
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/interprocess/detail/in_place_interface.hpp(58): note: while compiling class template member function 'void boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::placement_destroy<T>::destroy_n(void *,::size_t,size_t &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=shm::ring_buffer
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/interprocess/detail/named_proxy.hpp(50): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::placement_destroy<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=shm::ring_buffer
1>        ]
1>C:\Users\johnc\main\extlibs\boost_1_65_1\boost/interprocess/detail/named_proxy.hpp(130): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::CtorArgN<T,false,const MESSAGE_RANGE_TYPE &>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=shm::ring_buffer
1>        ]
1>..\..\src\apex\APEXManager.cpp(365): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'T *boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::named_proxy<boost::interprocess::segment_manager<CharType,MemoryAlgorithm,IndexType>,T,false>::operator ()<const MESSAGE_RANGE_TYPE&>(const MESSAGE_RANGE_TYPE &) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=shm::ring_buffer,
1>            CharType=char,
1>            MemoryAlgorithm=boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family,boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void,ptrdiff_t,uintptr_t,0>,0>,
1>            IndexType=boost::interprocess::iset_index
1>        ]
1>..\..\src\apex\APEXManager.cpp(365): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'T *boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::named_proxy<boost::interprocess::segment_manager<CharType,MemoryAlgorithm,IndexType>,T,false>::operator ()<const MESSAGE_RANGE_TYPE&>(const MESSAGE_RANGE_TYPE &) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=shm::ring_buffer,
1>            CharType=char,
1>            MemoryAlgorithm=boost::interprocess::rbtree_best_fit<boost::interprocess::mutex_family,boost::interprocess::offset_ptr<void,ptrdiff_t,uintptr_t,0>,0>,
1>            IndexType=boost::interprocess::iset_index
1>        ]
1>Done building project "apex.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic size will only work if you specify the interprocess-memory allocator: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost/lockfree/allocator.html.

Sadly, though `spsc_queue` [*does* support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/lockfree.html) stateful allocators:

> Defines the allocator. boost.lockfree supports stateful allocator and is compatible with Boost.Interprocess allocators

It does NOT seem to support the `uses_allocator<>` protocol required to pass the allocator down to it's element (`shared_string`), not even when using `scoped_allocator_adaptor`¹.

I ran into this before:

- [spsc_queue over shared_memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075646/spsc-queue-over-shared-memory/30090339#30090339)
- [Shared-memory IPC synchronization (lock-free)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207546/shared-memory-ipc-synchronization-lock-free/22209595#22209595) (uses compile-time sized `spsc_queue`)

So my suggestion would be to remove one of the ingredients:

- make the element a non-dynamic container (containers of containers require scoped allocator awareness or explicit element construction always(
- make the queue fixed-size (this is usually a good idea for shared memory situations, IYAM)
- add a layer of indirection...

On the latter, you could make the queue store a manged `bip::shared_ptr<shared_string>` instead:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23a7a991e9efd587)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/containers/string.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp> // for Coliru
#include <boost/interprocess/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.hpp>

#include <iostream>

/// noisy - traces special members
struct noisy {
    noisy& operator=(noisy&&) noexcept { std::cout << "operator=(noisy&&)\n"; return *this;      } 
    noisy& operator=(const noisy&)     { std::cout << "operator=(const noisy&)\n"; return *this; } 
    noisy(const noisy&)                { std::cout << "noisy(const noisy&)\n";                   } 
    noisy(noisy&&) noexcept            { std::cout << "noisy(noisy&&)\n";                        } 
    ~noisy()                           { std::cout << "~noisy()\n";                              } 
    noisy()                            { std::cout << "noisy()\n";                               } 
};

namespace bip = boost::interprocess;
namespace blf = boost::lockfree;

namespace Shared {
    using Segment = bip::managed_mapped_file; // Coliru unsupported: managed_shared_memory;
    using Manager = Segment::segment_manager;
    template <typename T> using Alloc = bip::allocator<T, Manager>;

    using String = bip::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Alloc<char> >;

    // using Element = String;
    // For debug/demonstration
    struct Element : String, noisy { using String::String; }; // inherit constructors

    using Ptr = bip::managed_shared_ptr<Element, Segment>::type;

    using Buffer = blf::spsc_queue<Ptr, blf::allocator<Alloc<Ptr> > >;
}

static std::string unique_id_gen() {
    static std::atomic_size_t s_gen { 0 };
    return "buffer_element" + std::to_string(++s_gen);
}

int main() {
    struct shm_remove {
        shm_remove() { bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
        ~shm_remove() { bip::shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory"); }
    } remover;

    Shared::Segment segment(bip::create_only, "MySharedMemory", 4 << 20);

    auto& buffer = *segment.construct<Shared::Buffer>(bip::unique_instance)[1](20, segment.get_segment_manager());

    auto create = [&segment](auto&&... args) {
        return make_managed_shared_ptr(segment.construct<Shared::Element>(unique_id_gen().c_str())
                (
                    std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...,
                    segment.get_segment_manager()
                ), segment);
    };

    std::cout << "Pushing\n";

    for (auto msg : { "hello", "world", "bye", "cruel", "world" })
        buffer.push(create(msg));

    std::cout << "Popping\n";
    {
        Shared::Ptr into;
        while (buffer.pop(into)) {
            std::cout << "Popped: '" << *into << "'\n";
        }
        std::cout << "Going out of scope\n";
    } // RAII
    std::cout << "Out of scope\n";

    {
        // make sure any other owned queue elements are freed if the queue is destroyed before it's empty:
        for (auto msg : { "HELLO", "WORLD", "BYE", "CRUEL", "WORLD" })
            buffer.push(create(msg));

        std::cout << "Destroying buffer containing 5 elements\n";
        segment.destroy<Shared::Buffer>(bip::unique_instance);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Pushing
noisy()
noisy()
noisy()
noisy()
noisy()
Popping
Popped: 'hello'
~noisy()
Popped: 'world'
~noisy()
Popped: 'bye'
~noisy()
Popped: 'cruel'
~noisy()
Popped: 'world'
Going out of scope
~noisy()
Out of scope
noisy()
noisy()
noisy()
noisy()
noisy()
Destroying buffer containing 5 elements
~noisy()
~noisy()
~noisy()
~noisy()
~noisy()
```

---

¹ search my answers on how to use these with other containers of containers in shared memory

Comment: Why are the managed shared mem pointers necessary? Shouldn't it be possible to make a Buffer<String> as in [other of your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62515428/1433554) with spsc_queue with capacity defined during runtime?

Comment: @alex Sure, the Gist linked in the question was from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207546/shared-memory-ipc-synchronization-lock-free/22209595#22209595), which shows that, but for the compile-time-capacity version. The documentation requires ["T must have a default constructor" and "T must be copyable"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html), The string type doesn't satisfy that criterion, but the [shared pointer does](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/shared_ptr.html#idm46159920765440-bb)

Comment: (Note that even if you could teach spsc_queue to default-initialize using the segment manager, it would turn out to be pretty inefficient due to all the extraneous copying of `Elements` constructed in the segment).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am actually struggling to implement serialized cv::Mat exchange between processes and string seemed as a way forward. But it's out of the scope o this questions so posted a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64897387/how-to-construct-boost-spsc-queue-with-runtime-size-parameter-to-exchange-cvma).